# User Exists Echo - Register & Login

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am trying to echo 'exists' when I click submit on the login form but I am receiving a blank page. The website is connected to the database. Any comments, feedback or help is much appreciated.

My index file contains the form, and the page is connected to the following files.

**Init document:**

```
<?php
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
?>
```

**Login file:**

```
include 'core/init.php';

if (user_exists('contactme@jazsingh.com') === true) {
echo 'exists';
}


if (empty($_POST) === false) {
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($email) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a email and password';
} else if (user_exists($email) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that email. Have you registered?';
}
```

**Users file:**

```
<?php

function user_exists($email) {
$email = sanitize($email);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` =   '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

?>
```

Comment: Put this on top: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','On');` and check if you can see any warnings or error messages

Comment: I have put the error_reporting on the top of the login.php page, and I received no errors :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `if user_exists('contactme@jazsingh.com') === true`, just check the response of `user_exists('contactme@jazsingh.com')`.

At this time, you are expecting a bool but mysql_result return a string.

Or you will get false if no results, but no true if you have results.

Comment: I changed it as you said, but still receiving a blank page :( Im new to PHP & MYSQL this is my first attempt to allow users to login and register.

Comment: Ok in this case, do a var_dump of the user_exists('contactme@jazsingh.com') function :)

Comment: @JSINGH hold on I didn't read well your query, I will try something on my end.

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\wamp\www\test.php on line 10

Comment: @JSINGH how many results are you expecting with your COUNT ?
For me, everything works fine ...

Comment: Im not sure if I follow you entirely (sorry), my MYSQL database is set up as the following: 

| User ID (1) | email (above) | password | name | active (1)|

Comment: No I mean when you do: "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` =   '$email'" >> you are expecting only one result?

Comment: I want to say yes, just the result of the that email in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this:

```
function user_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` =   '$email'";
    var_dump($query);
    var_dump(mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0));

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

And post the outputs here please.

Comment: So I copy and paste that to the Users.php file and replace the original. 

And change-  if user_exists('contactme@jazsingh.com') === true < to > user_exists('contactme@jazsingh.com') . 

If so I am seeing no changes with the blank screen. I have also tried with if user_exists(

Comment: I must be really retarded when using PHP or just there is something small that is being overlooked.. most likely both, I really appreciate you helping me through these times (Y)

Comment: BLANK Screenn??? Well at least with the var_dump it shouldn't be blank... what LAMP are you using? Wamp? Something else?
If you do echo blabla before your if, yyou have something?

Comment: Im using MAMP. I have tested If my website is connected to the database by creating an error test in my connect file and tests were fine. But It seems to be an error when checking information in the database and outputting a result. Im just purely trying to echo if that email address exists in the email column then echo exists.

Comment: If you run the query alone in phpmyadmin, do you have any result?

Comment: Which query should I run in Phpmyadmin ? I have opened the Submit query box that has; SELECT * FROM   WHERE 1 <Already in

Answer (score 0):

In Phpmyadmin, paste this in que SQL tab:

```
SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` =   'contactme@jazsingh.com'
```

And give us the result.

Comment: > Your SQL query has been executed successfully < 

COUNT('user_id') 1. It does not show the email address column just the User_id

Comment: No, it shows the count of user_id found, so everything is ok on this side.

Well... On my side everything seems to be good... I dunno what's wrong with your code...

Comment: Thank you for helping me check if anything was wrong with my database, and thanks for the efforts (Y)